# Looking for Rabbi Avigdor Miller's reason for identifying his tape as E-1 instead of 1001

Tags: avigdor-miller

Rabbi Avigdor Miller used to begin his famous Thursday night shiur by announcing which number shiur it was. For example, he would say something to the effect of, "Tonight is number 950 in our series." But for some reason, on the Thursday night after shiur 1000, instead of just continuing with 1001 he said something like, "Tonight is shiur E-1, which means Extension 1 - a new series." I'm under the impression that Rabbi Miller was a very though out person and I was wondering if anyone knows why he chose to start using the E-1, E-2, E-3 pattern instead of continuing with 1001,1002,1003 etc?

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand the question. Maybe he just decided to start calling it Extension 1?

Comment: Perhaps because he really wanted to give Shiurim in Yiddish. Therefore he branded the English ones as an offshoot.

Comment: @halevi. The first 1000 were in english. And E-1 was in English. So it can't be that.

Answer (score 5):

As heard from one of his students, the letter "E" was intended to represent "Eleph", the Hebrew word for 1,000.

So he continued the same count, albeit in a more discreet manner.